# Why windows 10 requires .NET 3.5 on demand?

Tags: .net, installation, windows-8.1, windows-10

I'm executing my .NET application in a clean Windows 10. As far as I know, it has installed .NET Framkework 4.0 or 4.5 by default.

My application is compiled with .NET 4.0. When I execute it, windows shows up a popup saying that I need to install .NET 3.5.

[image]

- Do you know why?
- Is not .NET 4.0 or higher able to execute code from previous .NET Frameworks?

Maybe I have dependencies to .NET 2.0. What you suggest to do?

Comment: It does not seem that you were compiling the app against .NET 4. Double check please. Or you are able to indicate in app.config that you would like to run on .NET 4.

Comment: run this tool https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy and look if you still have a reference to .net 2.0/3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 4.0 does not replace .NET 3.5 and the dependencies are different. May I suggest compiling with 4.6 if possible. If this is not possible, Windows 10 will run .NET 3.5 without issue.  Further details can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Indeed, from that link, we see that .Net 3.5 provides CLR v2.0; .Net 4.0 and above provide CLR v4.0. Apps that are compiled against .Net 3.5 probably expect a 2.0 CLR.